# Setting up a search tool to match any cell containing a 1 in certain digit location(s)

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editing

I have a search tool I am developing in Excel. In Column "EU", I have cells, each containing a string of 124 digits. These strings consist of 0's and 1's. I have 124 characteristics that produce the 1 or 0..., and users may want to search for 1,2,3,4,5 etc. characteristics. For simplicity, let's say EU1 has string 0100100011.....and I want to find any cell that contains 0100100000 or possibly 0000100010 etc.
In other words I want to find any string containing a "1" in a specific digit location, possibly several 1's in several digit locations..........
Example
I want to test if any of these 3 combinations.....

0000010000000001000000000000010010000010000000100000010010010000000000101100100000100000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000001010001000000010010010010010000000100000010010010000000000100100100000100100000100000000000000000000000001000100
0000000000000110000010000010001001010000010000100000010010010000000000100100100001000100000100000000000000000000000001000100

have 1's in these locations......

1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000100000000000000000000000000000

if there are 1's in other locations that is fine, but not if the test condition has a 1 and the tested locations have a zero in that digit.

---

Putting it another way, and using more comprehensible examples,
pretend that my strings are only five characters long,
and that my first five strings are

```
EU1       10000
EU2       10001
EU3       11000 
EU4       11011
EU5       00001
```

I want to search for strings
where all of a designated list of character positions contain `1`s,
by comparing each of them to a variable search string
that contains `1` at all the positions where I want there to be a `1`. 
Zeros in the variable are wildcards. 
Another way to put it is that the search string acts as a mask.

For example, to find strings whose first two digits are `1`s
(don’t care about the rest)
I would want to specify `11000` and get matches to strings EU3 and EU4. 
(This might represent a search for objects that are **A**ngular AND **B**lue.) 
A search on `10000` (all objects that are **A**ngular)
should match on all the strings
whose first digit is `1`, namely EU1, EU2, EU3, and EU4. 
`11100` (all objects that are **A**ngular AND **B**lue AND **C**ircular)
should yield no match,
because no strings contain `1` in the place of the third digit. 
Conversely, `00000` should match all the strings,
because an all-zeros search string is a wildcard.

In table form:

```
Search string:   11000       10000       11100       00000
                 ↓↓          ↓           ↓↓↓
EU1              10000     → 10000       10000     → 10000
EU2              10001     → 10001       10001     → 10001
EU3            → 11000     → 11000       11000     → 11000
EU4            → 11011     → 11011       11011     → 11011
EU5              00001       00001       00001     → 00001
                                        (none)       (all)
```

Comment: I'm sorry that your data are 128 characters long.  A solution for your 128-character problem will probably work for 8 or 18 characters as well, and vice versa.  I suggest that "For simplicity" you scale down your problem so that your strings fit on one line — your actual data hurt my eyes.

Comment: I have 5 strings. String A)=10000, String B)=10001, String C)=11000 String, D)=11011, String E)=00001. I would like to compare each of these strings to a variable. So if Variable A)=11000 I would get a match to string C and D. If Var A)=10000, match on strings A,B,C, and D. If Var A)=11100, no match, because no strings contain "1" in the place of the 3rd digit. So any time a "1" shows up in the variable it is critical that the string contains the 1 as well. If the Variable A)=00000 then strings A,B,C,D, and E are all a match, as zeros in the variable are wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I put your data into Column `E`, starting in Row 2. 
I put the search string into cell `D2`. 
(Of course `D2` and Column `E` must be formatted as text,
or you must type a single quote (`'`) before every number.)

I chose the approach of using Excel’s native search capabilities. 
A search string of `11000` means we’re looking for values
where the first digit is a `1`, the second digit is a `1`,
and the third through fifth characters are anything. 
As you said, zeros in the variable (search string) are wildcards.

The standard representation of this wildcard is `11???` — so I set cell `D3` to

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D2, "0", "?")
```

The question didn’t specify how the result(s) should be presented. 
One way would be, for each value in Column `E`,
to indicate whether it is a match. 
We can do this by **search**ing each `E` value for the wildcard string. 
If it is found, `SEARCH` returns 1, otherwise it returns an error. 
So we can get an appropriate `TRUE` or `FALSE` value by putting

```
=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$3, E2)))
```

into `F2`, and dragging it down to cover all the `E` data. 
(Note that `FIND` doesn’t allow wildcard characters.)

But it might be more convenient to have a list of the indices
of the matching values.  We can get that by using `MATCH` to search the column. 
I put a 1 in cell `G1` and

```
=MATCH($D$3, INDEX($E$2:$E$99, G1):$E$99, 0) + G1
```

into cell `G2` (adjusting the `99`s to correspond to the last data row)
and drag/fill this down. 
This searches for the wildcard string (which is in `D3`) within the `E` column,
starting at the point of the previous match. 
This returns the *row* number of the matches;
e.g., “String D” (`11011`, which is in cell `E5`), is reported as 5. 
If you want “String D” to be reported as 4, that’s an easy adjustment.

Here are the results for the sample data you suggested:

[image: 11000]
     [image: 10000]
     [image: 11100]
     [image: 00000]

Of course cells `D3` and `G1` can be hidden. 
And, if you really need to start your data in Row 1, that can be arranged.

P.S. I have tested this with 124-character long values,
and both parts of the answer seem to work.

Comment: Scott, it's wonderful that you spent so much time on this to help a random stranger. I'm sitting at my desk this morning-all smiles, because I wasn't sure I would find resolution here. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, you clarified the question when I asked you to; it’s only fair that I acknowledge your effort.  I’m glad it helped you.  Just out of curiosity, which part of the answer are you using (Column `F` or `G`)?

Comment: I am using column f to hide all rows that do not give a result of true. I ended up with strings of 154 digits, so this would have been a nightmare any other way. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in column **EU** from **EU1** to **EU100**.  To find cells with your pattern match use:

```
Sub Finderr()
   For i = 1 To 100
      v = Cells(i, "EU").Text
      If Mid(v, 1, 1) = "1" And Mid(v, 70, 1) = "1" And Mid(v, 91, 1) = "1" Then
         MsgBox i
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

will output which rows containing matches.

Comment: So each search would require the user to program a custom string?  It would seem more practical if the user posts a position list (like 1, 70, 91), and the search is derived from that.  (Maybe that's the new and improved version 2.0 available in the paid version of the application.)

Comment: @fixer1234  My code is already compatible with your comments.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the "extra cost" front end so that the test string is built as needed rather than hard coded (freeware vs. commercial versions of your application).